# Unable to mount partition, gives error "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error."

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, filesystem

My Windows drive isn't booting and so I am trying to mount my windows drive, using the following command:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/mydrive/
```

Output:

```
mount: /mnt/mydrive: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

When I run `blkid`, following is the output that I get:

```
/dev/sda2: PARTUUID="bdc32b7d-02"
```

As you can see, `blkid` doesn't output a filesystem type. Even `blkid -o value -s TYPE /dev/sda2` or `lsblk -no FSTYPE /dev/sda2` give no outputs.

And when I run `df /dev/sda2`, following is the output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3985888     0   3985888   0% /dev
```

Following is the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   1126399   1124352   549M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1126400 104316927 103190528  49.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       104318974 468860927 364541954 173.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       104318976 468860927 364541952 173.8G 83 Linux
```

I don't know how to solve this error, would appreciate any tips or assistance. Please let me know if you need some more data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help. https://wiki.epfl.ch/icit/kb/linux-mount-ntfs-with-permissions

Comment: NTFS-3g is an open-source tool that helps the Linux Operating system to support read and write, and without this utility, you will not be able to write data on it. 
sudo apt install ntfs-3g